# Cross browser Issue with Drupal Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: theming, navigation

I have a website that I am created for my company (Drupal & Bootstrap 3) and am having some trouble making the navigation work in all browsers. Essentially, there are two menu's that I am using in order to make this work. The default Drupal menu is supposed to be shown in XS and SM screen sizes and the Superfish menu with dropdown/hover support is supposed to show on MD and LG screen sizes. I have been able to make this work through CSS (Display:none) in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge browsers. However, when I try to use the website in Internet Explorer both menu's are showing up and at the MD screen size and as the viewport shrinks.. something is happening that I cannot figure out.

Can someone please take a look and let me know what they think? I am desperate and after many hours cannot find a solution. The link to the website is www.collegebodybuilding.net/grazzini_bootstrap. Any suggestions for the proper way of doing this would be greatly appreciated as well (I realize this is probably a mess and not the right way of doing things).

Comment: This is not a "Drupal" question. Instead this is "Bootstrap" question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have html5shiv and respond.js included for IE8 as recommended???

There's a whole section of bootstrap's getting started docs for IE8

[you can follow the link from here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9)